# Is there an easier way to deploy a Stored Procedure into multiple database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored proc saved as a SQL file and would like to deploy it to several databases.

What are my current options as I am not sure how to start creating a script for this. Should I use dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at sql server change management tools such as Red Gate. I don't know how dynamic sql would play into deploying sp's across multiple networks.

Comment: We have a tool called SQL Multi Script that will suit your purpose. All tools come with a 14-day trial.